# How do you reference the parent scope in an embed with twig?

Tags: symfony, scope, twig, embed

I want to add a block to a template that can be overwritten by a child template. The problem is I want to put this block in an embed, which has its own scope.

Does anyone know how to specify the scope you're working in with embeded templates?

```twig
{# base.html.twig #}

{% embed "AcmeBundle:component.html.twig" %}
  {% block header %}
    <h2>Foo!!</h2>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block content %}
    {% block content_set_by_child %}{% endblock %}
  {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

```twig
{# child.html.twig #}

{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block content_set_by_child %}
  <p>Bar!!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what about http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that embeds create a new block scope, and thus you can't overwrite them in parent templates. To get around this, I used `set` which seems to access the parent scope.

```twig
{# main.html.twig #}

{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% set inner_html %}
  <p>Bar!!</p>
{% enset %}
```

```twig
{# base.html.twig #}

{% embed "AcmeBundle:component.html.twig" %}
  {% block header %}
    <h2>Foo!!</h2>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block content %}
    {{ inner_html }}
  {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

[Pre-fix fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/nzkekx)

[Post-fix fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/sdf6oq)